# Does a critical graph have to be product-irreducible?

Tags: graph-theory

A finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is said to be *(vertex-)critical* if for all $v\in V$ we have $\chi(G\setminus\{v\}) < \chi(G)$.

Let me add that in this context, $\chi(\cdot)$ denotes the [chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), and by $G\setminus\{v\}$ we mean the graph $\big(V\setminus\{v\}, E\cap [V\setminus\{v\}]^2\big)$, where $[X]^2 :=\big\{\{x,y\}:x\neq y \in X\big\}$ for any set $X$.

**Question.** Is there a vertex-critical graph $G = (V,E)$ with $|V|> 1$ and $G \cong H_1\times H_2$ for some graphs $H_1, H_2$? (Here, $H_1 \times H_2$ denotes the [categorical, or tensor, product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of graphs.)

Comment: I think you should specify what product on graphs you are considering here (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs). Also clearly you mean to assume $H_1$ and $H_2$ have more than one vertex.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of the categorical product of graphs and will put this in the question. Apologies for the ambiguity.

Comment: @SamHopkins Actually, in the context of the tensor product, you don't need to explicitly exclude the one point graph $G_1$, because $G\times G_1$ is always a graph with no edges (all points are isolated), and vertex-critical graphs are always connected

Comment: $G\setminus\{v\}$ means removing all adjacent edges as well. If so, since the Euler-characteristic of a graph is the number of vertices minus the number of edges, vertex-cricical just means that at every vertex there are at least to edges. Thus for example $C_3\times C_2 \cong C_6$ is an example.

Comment: @HenrikRüping I believe $\chi(G)$ here denotes the chromatic number rather than the Euler characteristic.